# How to save encrypted FileSource data to byte array?

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

This is the code of Crypto++ FileSource to encrypt a large file. Its works perfectly but all in blackbox and doesn't allow me to save encrypted data to a byte array when encrypting. I want to know the mechanism beneath in order to save the temporary data. The document seem to be interface provided only, in [FileSource Class Reference](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_file_source.html).

```cxx
EAX< Blowfish >::Encryption e1;
e1.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, sizeof(iv));

FileSource fs1(ofilename.c_str(), true,
    new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(e1,
        new FileSink(efilename.c_str())));
```

Hope someone can tell me the mechanism or somewhere where I can learn about it.

Comment: Don't use Blowfish, use AES (Advanced Encryption Standard), even the creator of Blowfish uses AES now.

Comment: Yes. But its just for example, my problem is FileSource mechanism, not which algorithm is used.

Comment: You must learn streaming.

Answer (score 0):

> ... and doesn't allow me to save encrypted data to a byte array when encrypting. I want to know the mechanism beneath in order to save the temporary data.

Its not really clear to me what you want to do with a temporary array, so the answers below may not be correct.

There are two ways to create a temporary result in an array. First is a serial operation where you encrypt the file into an array, and then write the array to disk. Second is a parallel operation where both the array and encrypted file are created at the same time.

You can't use a C++11 `std::array` because the size of the array is *not* known at runtime. You can use a `std::vector`, and a snippet is provided blow.

---

***Serial***

```cxx
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

#include "osrng.h"
#include "eax.h"
#include "modes.h"
#include "blowfish.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "files.h"

using namespace CryptoPP;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SecByteBlock key(Blowfish::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH), iv(Blowfish::BLOCKSIZE);
    string ifilename("config.h"), ofilename("config.h.enc");

    memset(key, 0x00, key.size());
    memset(iv, 0x00, iv.size());

    EAX< Blowfish >::Encryption enc;
    enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, sizeof(iv));

    ifstream strm(ifilename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
    size_t len = strm.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end).tellg();
    strm.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    cout << "Data size: " << len << ", tag size: " << enc.TagSize() << endl;

    FileSource fs1(strm, false);
    len += enc.TagSize();

    cout << "Expected encrypted data and tag size: " << len << endl;
    len += Blowfish::BLOCKSIZE;
    cout << "Overcommitted encrypted data and tag size: " << len << endl;

    unique_ptr<byte[]> ptr(new byte[len]);
    ArraySink as1(ptr.get(), len);

    fs1.Detach(new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(enc, new Redirector(as1)));
    fs1.PumpAll();

    len = as1.TotalPutLength();
    cout << "Encrypted data and tag size: " << as1.TotalPutLength() << endl;

    ArraySource as2(ptr.get(), len, true, new FileSink(ofilename.c_str()));

    return 0;
}
```

The serial example produces:

```
$ ./test.exe
Data size: 38129, tag size: 8
Expected encrypted data and tag size: 38137
Overcommitted encrypted data and tag size: 38145
Encrypted data and tag size: 38137

$ ls -l config.*
-rw-r--r--. 1 ... 38223 Nov 19 04:40 config.compat
-rw-r--r--. 1 ... 38129 Nov 19 04:40 config.h
-rw-r--r--. 1 ... 38137 Nov 19 06:03 config.h.enc
```

---

***Parallel***

```cxx
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

#include "osrng.h"
#include "eax.h"
#include "modes.h"
#include "blowfish.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "channels.h"

using namespace CryptoPP;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SecByteBlock key(Blowfish::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH), iv(Blowfish::BLOCKSIZE);
    string ifilename("config.h"), ofilename("config.h.enc");

    memset(key, 0x00, key.size());
    memset(iv, 0x00, iv.size());

    EAX< Blowfish >::Encryption enc;
    enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, sizeof(iv));

    ifstream strm(ifilename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
    size_t len = strm.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end).tellg();
    strm.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    // Overcommit
    len += enc.TagSize() + Blowfish::BLOCKSIZE;

    // The one and only source
    FileSource fs1(strm, false);

    // The first sink
    FileSink fs2(ofilename.c_str(), true);

    // The second sink
    unique_ptr<byte[]> ptr(new byte[len]);
    ArraySink as1(ptr.get(), len);

    // The magic to output to both sinks
    ChannelSwitch cs;
    cs.AddDefaultRoute(as1);
    cs.AddDefaultRoute(fs2);

    fs1.Detach(new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(enc, new Redirector(cs)));
    fs1.PumpAll();

    return 0;
}
```

The parallel example produces:

```
$ ./test.exe

$ ls -l config.*
-rw-r--r--. 1 ... 38223 Nov 19 04:40 config.compat
-rw-r--r--. 1 ... 38129 Nov 19 04:40 config.h
-rw-r--r--. 1 ... 38137 Nov 19 06:02 config.h.enc
```

---

***std::vector***

Instead of:

```
unique_ptr<byte[]> ptr(new byte[len]);
ArraySink as1(ptr.get(), len);
```

You can use:

```
std::vector<byte> v;
...

v.resize(len);
ArraySink as(&v[0], v.size());
...

// Perform encryption
fs.Detach(new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(enc, new Redirector(as)));
fs.PumpAll();

// Resize now you know the size of ciphertext and tag
v.resize(as.TotalPutLength());
```

Comment: I ran the codes above with Visual C++ 2013, and both given me an error: Unhandled exception at 0x75F1A6F2 in abc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CryptoPP::FileStore::ReadErr at memory location 0x0116E5A0. Is it a platform dependent error? I tried it on Ubuntu, got the same error CryptoPP::FileStore::ReadErr

Comment: @Andiana - My apologies that the help I have been trying to provide has not been helpful. Perhaps you should learn more about C++ before you continue with the Crypto++ library.